# WP hook to add custom content after the_title()

Tags: hooks

I want to display a custom HTML snippet after a page or post title.

Any theme which follows the WP guidelines will output the post or page title using `the_title()`. For example, the [TwentyTwentyOne WP theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/blob/trunk/template-parts/content/content-single.php) does it as follows:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <header class="entry-header alignwide">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        <?php twenty_twenty_one_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </header>

...
```

So, my first attempt has been to use [the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) filter.

```
function filter_the_title( $title ) {
    return $title . '<h2>Whatever</h2>';
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'My\Namespace\filter_the_title' );
```

But this does filter the title text itself, not the whole output, so my custom HTML will be inside the `<h1>` tag.

How may I add custom content after `the_title()` output, without touching the theme files (should work as a plugin for any standard WP theme).

Comment: `the_title` only has a filter for the content and not the complete structure, kind of annoying I agree. You could create your own function that uses `get_the_title`, or just use `get_the_title`. PHP also has [runkit_function_redefine](http://phpweb.hostnet.com.br/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) but that will require you to have `PECL runkit` and php version >= 7.0

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Thanks for this interesting information.

Comment: Themes don't necessarily always use the arguments for `the_title()`, so even if you could filter outside them you still wouldn't be outside the heading tags on many themes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce your own hook (that's how I'd do it).
I've added a custom hook in the following snippet:

```
<header class="entry-header alignwide">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <?php do_action('custom_after_title_hook'); ?>
    <?php twenty_twenty_one_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</header>
```

In order for this to work, you need to have:

1. Access to the header.php
2. OR overwrite it in a child-theme.

Last thing is easy: just call the function in your functions.php file like this:

```
<?php

    function custom_after_title_hook(){

         $some_var = '<span>some text after title</span>';

         return $some_var;
    }
    add_action('my_custom_action', 'custom_after_title_hook');

?>
```

You can also add this to a plugin, but then you need to work with 'template_include'.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I cannot touch the theme files nor create a child theme, since this is expected to work for any theme via a plugin.

Comment: the_title() function uses get_the_title() function, where your filter fires. Result of your filter will be wraped with h1 tags after, that's why you get h2 tags inside h1 tag.